# Link to a different view's template from one template Django

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwhnX.png)

I have a template that displays a detail of a dorm with a list of "room_numbers".

The problem:
I am trying to make "room_numbers" as a link to each specific dorm room details page (see screenshot above). A dorm room details page has the following format: *rooms/<int:pk>* as specified in my urls.py

I have scoured through the web and can't find where I need to start. Django and Python newbie here so please bear with me.

URLs.py >

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('list/', views.DormsListView.as_view(), name='dorms'),
    path('list/<int:pk>', views.DormsDetailView.as_view(), name='dorm-detail'),
    path('rooms/', views.DormsRoomView.as_view(), name='rooms'),
    path('rooms/<int:pk>', views.DormsRoomsDetailView.as_view(), name='rooms-detail'),
 ]
```

Views.py (DormsDetailView) >

```
class DormsDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Dorm

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['room_numbers'] = ", ".join(self.object.dormroom_set.values_list('room_number', flat=True))
        return context
```

Views.py (DormRoomsDetailView) >

```
class DormsRoomsDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = DormRoom
```

Dorm_Detail.html >

```
<div>Rooms: {{ room_numbers }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it directly in the template. Return the list of room numbers, instead of the string with the commas, and then build the logic in the template, including the links.

Something like that:

```
class DormsDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Dorm

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['room_numbers'] = self.object.dormroom_set.values_list('room_number', flat=True)
        return context
```

Then, in the template:

```
<div>
    Rooms: 
    {% for room_number in room_numbers %}
        <a href="{% url 'rooms-detail' room_number %}">{{ room_number }}</a>{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The `{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}` part is just to add the commas between the room numbers, like you had on the view. But when it's the last iteration, it won't print the comma.

Comment: How can I use the id instead of room_number in the url but retain the room_number as <a> text?

Comment: Fixed by changing the context to "id","number" and displaying the context in template using room_numers.0 and room_numbers.1.

Not sure if this is the right way but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of turning your list into a string with `", ".join()` could you leave it as a list? In `Dorm_Detail.html` you could then loop over them.

```
{% for room in room_numbers %}
      <a href="#"> {{ room }} </a>
{% endfor %}
```

That should display all the room numbers as a separate link. Hope I understood the question properly!

Comment: I am trying to link each room to: rooms/<int:pk>
<br/><br/>
Example,<br/>
room 1 - should link to rooms/1<br/>
room 2 - should link to rooms/2<br/>
etc.

Comment: Right, you'd just have to change the value of the `href`.